# Unable to process the pipe function

Tags: c, pipe

Unable to process the pipe function where a give pipes in which one process sends a string message to a second process, and the second process reverses the case of each character in the message and sends it back to the first process.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <sys/wait.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <assert.h>
  #include <stdbool.h>

   //  Parent: reads from P1_READ, writes on P1_WRITE
  //  Child:  reads from P2_READ, writes on P2_WRITE 

#define P1_READ     0
#define P2_WRITE    1
#define P2_READ     2
#define P1_WRITE    3

 // the total number of pipe *pairs* we need
 #define NUM_PIPES   2
 /*
 toggleString accepts an a pointer to char array, allocates size for the     
 string to be toggled,
  copys the argument into a string, loops through the string and for every  
 uppercase character 
 we set it to its lower case counterpart and vice versa, returning the  
  toggled string
  */
  char *toggleString(char *argv){

 int i;      /* Declare counter */

 char *str = malloc(sizeof(argv[1]));  /* Declare array sizeof input */

 strcpy(str, argv);    /* Copy String to char array */

 for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++) { //Loop through length of string

    if(str[i]>='A'&&str[i]<='Z'){ //if the array at i is uppercase

     str[i]+=32;            //Make it lower case

   } else if (str[i]>='a'&&str[i]<='z') {//  if the array at i is lowercase 

    str[i]-=32;             //Make it uppercase

    }

 }

   return str;

   }

  /*
    int inputValidation accept and integer (number of arugments) and a     
 pointer to the cmd line input array  
  We check to see if the command line input contains the minimal number of    
 arugments and check to see    
  whether or not the user input contains at least one reversible haracter,    
if all goes well we return 0 
 */
   int inputValidation(int argc, char *argv[]){

   int i;          //Declare counter variable

   bool c = false; //Declare boolean flag using imported <stdbool.h>

   char str[strlen(argv[1])];  //Declare str

   strcpy(str, argv[1]); //copy argument into str

   if (argc != 2)  {  // check to see if we have enough arguments to   
   continue     
                      // Prompt user of correct usage

   fprintf(stderr, "\nUsage: %s <string> or <'string 1, string 2', ...,                 

    string n'> for multiple strings\n", argv[0]);

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    //Exit on improper input

   } else {
                //loop through our string
     for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++) {
                //if any any char is a reversible character
     if(isalpha((int) str[i])){

        c = true; //set the flag to true

    } 

    }

     if(c == false){ //If flag is false input does not contain any 

     reversible charachters

          printf("\nSorry, The string you entered did NOT contain any      

       Alphabetical Characters\nRun me again, with at least 1 Alphabetical      

      character\n\n");

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //Exit on improper input

    }

  return (0);

   }    

     }
```

/*
      Main takes input from command line, calls input validation to make sure of
    proper input,
    then creates the pipes we will need and the forks the child process, Parent
   and Child 
      execute they're respective code
    */

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   assert(argc>1);

   int fd[2*NUM_PIPES];    //Declare int[] of file descriptors

   int len, i;             //Declare length and integer for count

   pid_t pid;              //Declare process id

   char parent[strlen(argv[1])];   //Declare Parent array

 char child[strlen(argv[1])];    //Declare Child array

 if(inputValidation(argc, argv) == 0) /* Check for proper input */

   strcpy(parent, argv[1]); 

// create all the descriptor pairs we need
   for (i=0; i<NUM_PIPES; ++i)
   {
    if (pipe(fd+(i*2)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate pipes");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
   }

// fork() returns 0 for child process, child-pid for parent process.
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
    perror("Failed to fork process");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
//////////////////////////////Childs Code     
BEGINS//////////////////////////////////


// if the pid is zero, this is the child process
   if (pid == 0)
   {
    // Child. Start by closing descriptors we
    //  don't need in this process
    close(fd[P1_READ]);
    close(fd[P1_WRITE]);

    // used for output
    pid = getpid();

    // wait for parent to send us a value
    len = read(fd[P2_READ], &child, len);
    if (len < 0)
    {
        perror("Child: Failed to read data from pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (len == 0)
    {
        // not an error, but certainly unexpected
        fprintf(stderr, "Child: Read EOF from pipe");
    }
    else
    {

          // report pid to console
        printf("Child(%d): Recieved Message\n\nChild(%d): Toggling Case and  
     Sending to Parent\n",pid, pid);

        // send the message to toggleString and write it to pipe//
        if (write(fd[P2_WRITE], toggleString(child), strlen(child)) < 0)
        {
            perror("Child: Failed to write response value");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        }

    }

    // finished. close remaining descriptors.
    close(fd[P2_READ]);
    close(fd[P2_WRITE]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   //child code ends///
//////////////////////////////Parent Code    
 BEGINS//////////////////////////////////

  // Parent. close unneeded descriptors
  close(fd[P2_READ]);
  close(fd[P2_WRITE]);

  // used for output
  pid = getpid();

  // send a value to the child

   printf("\nParent(%d): Sending %s to Child\n\n", pid, argv[1]);
   if (write(fd[P1_WRITE], argv[1], strlen(argv[1])) != strlen(argv[1]))
   {
    perror("Parent: Failed to send value to child ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  // now wait for a response
   len = read(fd[P1_READ], &parent, strlen(parent));
   if (len < 0)
   {
    perror("Parent: failed to read value from pipe");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   else if (len == 0)
   {
    // not an error, but certainly unexpected
    fprintf(stderr, "Parent(%d): Read EOF from pipe", pid);
  }
  else
  {
    // report what we received
    printf("\nParent(%d): Received %s from Child\n\n", pid, parent);
   }

   // close down remaining descriptors
   close(fd[P1_READ]);
    close(fd[P1_WRITE]);

   // wait for child termination
  wait(NULL);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

  }
   //////////////////////////////Parent Code     
 ENDS//////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: please chose one language c or C++

Comment: This isn't valid C++ code.

Comment: If you format your code more neatly it is much easier for others to read. I won't even look at code that is not properly indented.

Comment: `char *str = malloc(sizeof(argv[1])); strcpy(str, argv);` Buffer overflow right here. `argv` is a pointer to `char`, therefore `argv[1]` is a `char`, therefore `sizeof argv[1]` is `sizeof (char)` is `1`.

Comment: Note that you don't send the null byte down the pipe so the receiver gets an array of bytes and not a string and you can't apply `strlen()` reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define P1_READ     0
#define P2_WRITE    1
#define P2_READ     2
#define P1_WRITE    3

#define NUM_PIPES   2

static
char *toggleString(char *argv)
{
    int i;

    char *str = malloc(strlen(argv) + 1);  /* Key Fix */

    strcpy(str, argv);

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            str[i] += 32;
        }
        else if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        {
            str[i] -= 32;
        }
    }

    return str;
}

static
int inputValidation(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool c = false;

    char str[strlen(argv[1])];

    strcpy(str, argv[1]);

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nUsage: %s <string> or <'string 1, string 2', ..., string n'> for multiple strings\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            if (isalpha((int)str[i]))
            {
                c = true;
            }
        }

        if (c == false)
        {
            printf("\nSorry, The string you entered did NOT contain any"
                   " Alphabetical Characters\nRun me again, with at least 1 Alphabetical"
                   " character\n\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        return(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    assert(argc > 1);

    int fd[2 * NUM_PIPES];
    int len, i;
    pid_t pid;
    char parent[strlen(argv[1])];
    char child[strlen(argv[1])];

    if (inputValidation(argc, argv) == 0)
        strcpy(parent, argv[1]);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_PIPES; ++i)
    {
        if (pipe(fd + (i * 2)) < 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to allocate pipes");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to fork process");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd[P1_READ]);
        close(fd[P1_WRITE]);

        pid = getpid();

        len = read(fd[P2_READ], child, sizeof(child));
        if (len < 0)
        {
            perror("Child: Failed to read data from pipe");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (len == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Child: Read EOF from pipe\n");
        }
        else
        {
            child[len] = '\0';
            printf("Child(%d): Received Message [%s]\nChild(%d): Toggling Case and Sending to Parent\n", pid, child,  pid);
            char *toggled = toggleString(child);
            printf("Child(%d): Sending [%s]\n", pid, toggled);

            if (write(fd[P2_WRITE], toggled, len) < 0)
            {
                perror("Child: Failed to write response value");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            free(toggled);
        }

        close(fd[P2_READ]);
        close(fd[P2_WRITE]);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    close(fd[P2_READ]);
    close(fd[P2_WRITE]);

    pid = getpid();

    printf("\nParent(%d): Sending [%s] to Child\n\n", pid, argv[1]);
    len = strlen(argv[1]);
    if (write(fd[P1_WRITE], argv[1], len) != len)
    {
        perror("Parent: Failed to send value to child");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    len = read(fd[P1_READ], parent, sizeof(parent));
    if (len < 0)
    {
        perror("Parent: failed to read value from pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (len == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Parent(%d): Read EOF from pipe\n", pid);
    }
    else
    {
        parent[len] = '\0';
        printf("\nParent(%d): Received [%s] from Child\n\n", pid, parent);
    }

    close(fd[P1_READ]);
    close(fd[P1_WRITE]);

    wait(NULL);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It was painful extracting your code from your comments, and the split over multiple line strings, and so on.  The `toggleString()` function was broken — allocating 1 byte and then copying a string over that.  The other code was not careful about null-terminating strings and handling them.  These are basically the problems diagnosed in the comments.

Sample run:

```
$ pp53 'AbSoLuTeLy GlOrIoUs'

Parent(5209): Sending [AbSoLuTeLy GlOrIoUs] to Child

Child(5210): Received Message [AbSoLuTeLy GlOrIoUs]
Child(5210): Toggling Case and Sending to Parent
Child(5210): Sending [aBsOlUtElY gLoRiOuS]

Parent(5209): Received [aBsOlUtElY gLoRiOuS] from Child

$
```